# How do I center background image

Tags: html, css

So, I have a big image with logotype in the center, and thing that I asking for is how do I horizontally center the image, if screen width changes or varies between different devices?

I saw few solutions using "img" tag, but I need to know how to center background specifically.

```
body
{
  background-image: url('website-bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It's OK on big screen, but I am not sure that my screen big enough to display website with various resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background-position property, and set it to "center":

`background-position: center;`

Answer (score 0):

Background Position Center will center your background image.

```
background-position: center;

body
{
  background-image: url('website-bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```